# Animation on recyclerview item click

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

[image]
Anyone knows how to remove that black animation, appearing on recyclerview item **click**

Comment: Post your code to understand your animation problem.

Comment: I didn't added any animation, all the things are default, that's why i didn't posted code. I just want to remove that ripple animation on click

Comment: if you added this 'android:animateLayoutChanges=true' in your item layout, then remove it.

Comment: no, Its not there

Answer (score 0):

Just add below line to your code

```
recyclerView.setItemAnimator(null);
```