# Animation when clicking on the recyclerview element

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-animation

I need to make an animation similar to a dropdown list when i click on the recyclerview element. In the item 2 xml markup, 1 is the main one, the second one becomes visible when clicked. According to the idea, it should be like this: I clicked on the element, it opened with a dropout animation. When pressed again, it closed. Also with animation. At the moment, the elements just abruptly appear and also abruptly disappear. I would not like to use third-party libraries, if there is such a possibility. I want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65228427/animation-on-recyclerview-item-click)

```
holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (!flag) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, MessageActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("userid", user.getId());
            mContext.startActivity(intent);

        } else if(holder.info.getVisibility()==View.GONE) { 
            holder.info.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        } else {
            holder.info.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
    }
);
```

In this section of code, I either open message activity, or open additional information about the user.

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/info_about">
            ///Info about users(username and him photo)

        </RelativeLayout>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/info_about"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="45dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:id="@+id/info">

            ///Info about users(call_number, email... When i clicked on item)
        </LinearLayout>
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this...

```
holder.binding.cardview.setOnClickListener(v -> {


                    if (holder.binding.expandableView.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(holder.binding.cardview, new AutoTransition());
                        holder.binding.expandableView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(holder.binding.cardview, new AutoTransition());
                        holder.binding.expandableView.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                    if (holder.binding.playlayout.getVisibility()==View.GONE){
                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(holder.binding.cardview, new AutoTransition());
                        holder.binding.playlayout.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    } else {
                        TransitionManager.beginDelayedTransition(holder.binding.cardview, new AutoTransition());
                        holder.binding.playlayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    }

                });
            }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what is the binding in your solution? My clicklistener looks like this: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {some code....